# fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch

Tags: git, github, git-push

Пытаюсь запушить проект на гитхаб в пустой репозиторий, но при вводе комманды `git push origin` или же `git push` выдает ошибку:

```
$ git push origin
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401652/fatal-the-current-branch-master-has-no-upstream-branch Возможно у вас вдухфакторная авторизация включена.

Comment: да, там смотрел уже. сейчас проверю

Comment: на гитхабе двух факторной аутентификации нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема решена при помощи этой комманды:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: эта команда выдает ту же самую ошибку